# Enable diffing for RSpec array matcher

Tags: arrays, ruby, rspec, diff, matcher

RSpec provides a "diff"-style output when comparing multi-line strings.  Is there a way to do something similar when comparing arrays (other than converting the array to a multi-line string)?

Comment: Is [`match_array`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers:match_array) what you're looking for? If not, then what desired behaviour does it lack?

Comment: @TomLord `match_array` doesn't take the order of elements into account, i.e. `expect([1,2,3]).to match_array([3,2,1])` passes.

Comment: In my case, order is important.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that's what you wanted. But you're actually just after a "nicer" error message when a standard `eq` matcher fails?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly it.  The output is long enough that it can be difficult to find the difference when the matcher fails.

Comment: What about using a custom error message? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-6/docs/customized-message

Comment: A custom error message is a possible solution.  The link you shared applies to a specific example only.  I wouldn't want to repeat the customization for each example.  I was also hoping to avoid having to write my own diff.   (Although that is certainly not out of the question.)

Comment: The solution shown here does what I want --- except for the warning against using `RSpec::Differ` directly.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551564/how-to-write-a-diffable-matcher-with-rspec2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but I don't think this feature is built-in to RSpec.

However, you could [implement a custom matcher with a custom error message](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-6/docs/custom-matchers/define-a-custom-matcher#overriding-the-failure-message):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define(:eq_array) do |expected|
  match { |actual| expected == actual }

  failure_message do |actual|
    <<~MESSAGE
      expected: #{expected}
      got:      #{actual}

      diff:     #{Diffy::Diff.new(expected.to_s, actual.to_s).to_s(:color)}
    MESSAGE
  end
end

# Usage:

expect([1, 2, 3]).to eq_array([1, 4, 3])
```

This demo is using the [`diffy`](https://github.com/samg/diffy) library; you could implement this however you see fit.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  The key for me was figuring out how to call the built-in differ.  An older article cautioned against using the differ directly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551564/how-to-write-a-diffable-matcher-with-rspec2